# python extract key from json file doesn't work

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am new to python and I am using python 3.9.13 trying to extract values from existing keys in a json file.
I know that `json.load()` function outputs a dictionary so at the last part of my code I am searching in a dictionary.

Here is my python code:

```
import os
import json

with open('./output.json', 'r') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

values= []

if "created" in data:
    print("Key found!")
    print ("Version: ", data["version"], "created at: ", data["created"])
    values.append(data["version"])

print(values)
```

Here is the output.json file I am reading from:

```
{
  "section1": [
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "apiVersion": "v2",
      "appVersion": "1.0.22",
      "type": "application",
      "created": "2022-05-03T11:20:45Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "description": "",
      "apiVersion": "v2",
      "appVersion": "1.0.22",
      "type": "application",
      "created": "2022-04-20T13:55:16Z"
    }
  ],
  "section2": [
    {
      "name": "name2",
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "apiVersion": "v2",
      "appVersion": "1.0.17",
      "type": "application",
      "created": "2022-01-25T07:58:09Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "name2",
      "version": "2.0.1",
      "description": "",
      "apiVersion": "v2",
      "appVersion": "1.0.17",
      "type": "application",
      "created": "2022-01-18T07:08:38Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I expect my array `values` to be:

```
[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1]
```

But my output is an empty array and I cannot figure out why.

Would appreciate your help!

Comment: print `data` and you will recognize that it is a dict with keys mapped to a list which contains a dict that has `version` as key. Adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: `data` is the outer dict, with keys like `"section1"`, you have to iterate over the values in the outer dict, which are your inner dicts, then you can do like `values.append(inner["version"])`

Comment: just for clarification, is there any significance to the `created` key? i.e. it looks like you only care about the values for `version` keys, do you also need to check if a `created` key exists?

Comment: If your expected value `[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1]`  then why these print statetment `print("Key found!")
     print ("Version: ", data["version"], "created at: ", data["created"])
    values.append(data["version"])`.  The easiest onliner shell script is `for i in 1 2; do cat output.json | jq .section$i[].version ; done`

Answer (score 0):

You're not respecting the dictionary hierarchy, when you call a key in a dict, it doesn't go through all the levels of that dictionary ...

Here's a changed version of your code that does the job :

```
import os
import json

with open('./output.json', 'r') as f:
    json_dict = json.load(f)

values= []

for section in json_dict.values():
    for el in section:
        print("Key found!")
        print ("Version: ", el["version"], "created at: ", el["created"])
        values.append(el["version"])

print(values)
```

output :

```
Key found!
Version:  1.0.0 created at:  2022-05-03T11:20:45Z
Key found!
Version:  1.0.1 created at:  2022-04-20T13:55:16Z
Key found!
Version:  2.0.0 created at:  2022-01-25T07:58:09Z
Key found!
Version:  2.0.1 created at:  2022-01-18T07:08:38Z
['1.0.0', '1.0.1', '2.0.0', '2.0.1']
```

Answer (score 0):

First, assuming `data` is a `dict` type, populated from JSON as above:

```py
data = json.load(f)
```

Then the simplest way to achieve the desired output, would be to use a nested `list` comprehension as follows:

```py
>>> [dct['version'] for lst in data.values() for dct in lst]
['1.0.0', '1.0.1', '2.0.0', '2.0.1']
```

Note that the `list` comprehension above is basically the equivalent of two `for` loops:

```py
result = []
for lst in data.values():
    for dct in lst:
        result.append(dct['version'])
```

If you need to specifically check for the presence of a `"created"` key, or if you need to validate that you're iterating over `list` and `dict` types for example, you can instead use this approach:

```py
result = [dct['version'] for lst in data.values() if isinstance(lst, list)
          for dct in lst if isinstance(dct, dict) and 'created' in dct]
```